# How can I resolve foo's library path using g++ -Lhere -Lthere -lfoo without building an object?

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, resolution

I would like to display the explicit path to a library which will be used in the linking stage of compilation.  I want to do this so that I can add the library as a dependency to a separate object file.

In other words, I often link using:

g++ myFile.cpp -Lsomewhere -Lelse -Lhere -Lthere -lfoo

Is there a way to coerce g++, ld, ldd, or something else to resolve '-lfoo' using the -L's without actually linking anything so that I can use the explicit path as a dependency?  For more explicit info, see [Makefile Updated Library Dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200235/makefile-updated-library-dependency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't ideal, and I hope there is a cleaner answer, but you can get the default search paths from gcc, then search each one for the files. Here it is in GNU make:

```
libnams = foo bar
dirs = somewhere else here there
dirs += $(subst :, ,$(subst =,,$(word 2,$(shell gcc -print-search-dirs | grep libraries))))
exts = a so
paths = $(foreach L, $(libnams), \
           $(firstword $(foreach D, $(dirs), \
              $(foreach E, $(exts), \
                 $(wildcard $(D)/lib$(L).$(E))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the order in which the linker searches directories looking for the library in question ([see the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)), you can use Make's `vpath` to search them in the same order:

```
vpath %.so somewhere else here there

otherObjectFile: foo.so
  #whatever...
```