# makefile error ----> make: *** No rule to make target `mysql.h'

Tags: mysql, c, api, makefile

This might sound like a dumb question. But here goes..... I am using a C program called db_access.c which interacts with MySQL (in Ubuntu 10.10 with MySQL Server version: 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1 (Ubuntu)). Inside the program, I have: `include "mysql.h"`
When I do the following, everything works out right:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/mysql db_access.c -lmysqlclient -o db_access
./db_access
```

Problem arises when I try to integrate it into an existing (and working makefile). The contents of the makefile:

```
all: MappingServer

#Macro definitions
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -lm
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include/mysql
LIBS = -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient 

MappingServer.o: MappingServer.c map_registration.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c MappingServer.c

route_aggregation.o: route_aggregation.c map_registration.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c route_aggregation.c

db_access.o: db_access.c map_registration.h mysql.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c db_access.c 

MappingServer: MappingServer.o route_aggregation.o db_access.o
    $(CC) $(LIBS) -o MappingServer MappingServer.o route_aggregation.o db_access.o  

clean:
    -rm MappingServer.o route_aggregation.o db_access.o
```

I have two other C programs, MappingServer.c and route_aggregation.c. These 3 files need to be compiled together. By the way, I also did:

```
root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq/MappingServer# mysql_config --cflags
-I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing   -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX
```

and

```
    root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq/MappingServer# mysql_config --libs
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

So I think the paths are OK. When I do: `make all`
I get:

```
root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq/MappingServer# make all
gcc -lm -c MappingServer.c
gcc -lm -c route_aggregation.c
route_aggregation.c: In function ‘vtysh_input’:
route_aggregation.c:602: warning: function returns address of local variable
make: *** No rule to make target `mysql.h', needed by `db_access.o'.  Stop.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

the line

```
db_access.o: db_access.c map_registration.h mysql.h
```

tells make that `db_access.o` depends on `db_access.c`, `map_registration.h` and `mysql.h`. make complains because `mysql.h` cannot be found in the current directory (it's in `/usr/include/mysql`).

see the question [Makefile updated library dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3200235/112968) for how to specify libraries as dependencies in make

Answer (score 3):

You put "mysql.h" as a dependency, but it's not in the current directory, so Make thinks it needs to build it, but doesn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove all the lines like:

```
MappingServer.o: MappingServer.c map_registration.h
```

if the `map_registration.h`  is included in the c file, make is smart enough to find it. The only thing to be noticed may be to set the search file path using： `-I`.